VSCode directory based file associations with same extension ignored in workspace
I use the following .vscode/settings.json configuration:
{
    "ansible.python.interpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "files.associations": {
        ".github/worksflows/*.yaml": "github-actions-workflow",
        "*.j2": "ansible-jinja",
        "*.json5": "json",
        "*.yaml": "ansible"
    }
}

For some reason, .github/worksflows/*.yaml are always picked by Ansible, no matter how I format the directory. Both .github and .vscode directories are at root level, standard GitHub repo. I also tried placing .github/worksflows/*.yaml after *.yaml, with same results.
Other directory formats I tried, with same failed result:

*/worksflows/*.yaml
**/worksflows/*.yaml
.github/worksflows/docs.yaml
*/worksflows/docs.yaml
**/worksflows/docs.yaml
/.github/worksflows/*.yaml
/.github/worksflows/docs.yaml

I'm not sure what I miss or if this a bug, thank you for your help.
